# StreamWriter is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

I want a put a StreamWriter on C# program.  I already put **using System.IO;** on the top page. But i have got the error **"StreamWriter' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'**. The Program as below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace StreamWriter
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
            of.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
            richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textBox1.Text, true);
            sw.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Its a naming collision, you'r namespace `StreamWriter` have the same name as the class `StreamWriter`, you can either use another namespace or call on the `StreamWriter` class via `System.IO.StreamWriter`.

Comment: Thank you. i rename the StreamWriter. and it works.

Comment: Please mark Ulugbek Umirov's answer as correct so that the question is marked as solved. :)

Comment: i can't vote up because it said 'require 15 reputation'

Comment: Don't have to upvote, just mark it as correct (the V symbol). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared namespace `namespace StreamWriter` conflicting with class name. Rename your namespace to something different.

Comment: Thank you. It works. i rename it.

Answer (score 1):

Its a naming collision, your namespace `StreamWriter` have the same name as the class `StreamWriter`.
You can either use another namespace or call on the `StreamWriter` class via `System.IO.StreamWriter`.

I would recommend renaming your namespace tho.